# CSS comments without preceding space are not highlighted properly

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

See this CSS code block:

```css
hello people {
  i-am-sorry: i-could-not; /* I am a comment. I am highlighted properly */
  find-a-title: with-a-pun;/* I am a comment. I am highlighted wrongly */
}
```

For the people from the future once this is fixed, currently it looks like this:

[image: snapshot of current behavior]

[Prettify seems to work correctly](https://jsfiddle.net/y2r2L5vs/). So this seems a bug of the SO implementation.

Comment: There's not much SO can do about this, they use a 3rd party code syntax highlighting library *([Google Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify)?)* as far as I'm aware

Comment: Yep, discovered this [a few months back](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35478658/revisions) but didn't report it here for the reason @SeinopSys mentioned.

Comment: Has it been reported to the bug tracker of the third party developers?

Comment: @SeinopSys I think SO has a fair few options to fix it. Fork the 3rd party library, write an extension for it, report it to them as Jacco suggested, use a different library, roll their own...

Comment: @SeinopSys They may use it but you can bet it's been manipulated the heck out of. End of the day SE still have the power to fix it, like Michal points out.

Comment: For reference [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/202529) explains how Prettify is used and how to report bugs etc.

Comment: I recently noticed a similar glitch with `#` comments in Perl or Python code.  At the same time, when bare URLs appear in generic code blocks, the `//` **is** treated as the start of a comment.  Where we would *like* this failure to occur, it fails to.

Comment: [Prettify seems to work correctly](https://jsfiddle.net/y2r2L5vs/). So this seems a bug of the SO implementation.

Comment: Hard for me to get terribly excited about this bug. There should always be a space there, so the errant syntax highlighting just serves as a gentle reminder.

Comment: @Oriol I've edited your last comment into the first post for visibility.

Comment: @CodyGray But sometimes, if you use a space then a horizontal scrollbar appears because the text is too wide. Removing the space solves that, but then it looks wrong

Comment: @Oriol Then don't put a comment on the same line.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper But then it may not be clear if the comment belongs to the previous or following line. So I should also add newlines, and then the code block becomes too tall for my taste.

Comment: Given a choice between tall, wide, or cramped code blocks, I'll take tall any day of the week.